# Ruby on Rails install gem best_in_place

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Help to understand what the problem is - add to the project best_in_place gem. Gemfile:

```
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.0.1'
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs   
//= require best_in_place
//= require jquery-ui
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

tasks.coffe:

```
jQuery ->
      $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
```

Error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Tasks#index

Showing /Users/alexandr.dmitrenko/tasklist/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

couldn't find file 'best_in_place' with type 'application/javascript'
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjKZ4.png)

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` and restart your rails server after adding the gem to your Gemfile?

Comment: Restart . It solved the problem. But now the information is not displayed. [link](http://joxi.ru/82QYaobU140VD2). `<td id="task-name" style="width: 90%"><%= best_in_place @task, :name %> </td>`

Comment: Since that's unrelated to the problem you were just having, you should ask a new question for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `rails` to pick up the vendors of your newly installed `gems` you have to restart the server.